# Recursive String Concatenation over a Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I have a dictionary which holds the names of modules and as a value it holds a list of its submodules, each submodule is defined as ['Absolute Name', 'Relative Name'], the absoulute name is the name by which it can be found as key in my dictionary if such a module has been inserted into the dictionary.

```
modules_dict = {
    "ModuleB": [],
    "ModuleA": [
        [
            "ModuleB",
            "Realtive_B"
        ],
        [
            "ModuleC",
            "Relative_C"
        ],
    ],
    "ModuleC": [
        [
            "ModuleE",
            "Realtive_E"
        ],
        [
            "ModuleD",
            "Relative_D"
        ]] }
```

My goal is it to make "hierarchy" strings for each module/submodule where each string is that modules relative hierarchy.
For this example that would be:

```
ModuleA.Realtive_B
ModuleA.Relative_C.Realtive_E
ModuleA.Relative_C.Relative_D
ModuleA.Relative_C
```

The code I have written so far achieves this in some cases but if the hierarchy gets too complex there are duplicate fragments in some strings like:

```
ModuleA.RelativeB.RelativeC.RelativeA.RelativeB.RelativeG
```

At the start of my function I am passing it the root of the hierarchy it will be working with

```
hierarchy_strings = []

def name_change(submodules,upper_name):
    submodules[1] =upper_name+ "." + submodules[1] # submodules is a list containing absolute and relative name of a submodule ( the values of my dict )
    return submodules

def scan_submodule(module):
    try:
        for submodules in modules_dict[module[0]]:
            local_module_info = name_change(submodules,module[1])
            scan_submodule(local_module_info)
            hierarchy_strings.append(local_module_info[1])
            print(local_module_info[1])
    except KeyError:
        pass


top_module= ["ModuleA","ModuleA"]
scan_submodule(top_module)
```

There has to be a mistake in my way of thinking but I just cannot figure it out.

Comment: It's usually wrong to use a global variable in a recursive function. Pass the list as a parameter and don't modify it in place.

Comment: Why are you passing a list of two elements instead of just two separate arguments? You don't seem to be looping over the list.

Comment: You're also modifying the nested lists in `modules` when you assign to `submodules[1]`.

Comment: But from my understanding this does not change anything about the result of this function, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I'm just trying to understand what the 2 elements of the list represent in `scan_submodule`. It's better if you give them descriptive names.

Comment: Why do you want `ModuleA.Relative_C`  in the output, but not  `ModuleA`? Can you explain the logic behind that?

Comment: @trincot It looks like you use the absolute names just for chaining to the next module, only the relative names get put into the result.

Comment: @trincot Because I was not able to come up with a solution for that. Having also ModuleA in the Output would be even better.

Comment: @Barmar Thats correct, i want to chain the relative names together, the absolute names are only used for the lookup table

Comment: It would be clearer if you used dictionaries rather than lists, since lists are usually for homogeneous collections. E.g. `{"link": "A", "moduleName": "B"}`

Comment: could the typos `Realtive` vs `Relative` be causing some problem?  I don't really understand how the intended output `ModuleA.Relative_C.Realtive_E` is derived from the input... does it mean "all the children of `ModuleC` can also be found via `ModuleA.Relative_C`" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a recursive generator, like so:

```
def iterPaths(modules, root, path=""):
    if not path:  # Set default for path
        path = root
    yield path
    if root not in modules or not modules[root]:
        return
    for child, label in modules[root]:
        yield from iterPaths(modules, child, path + "." + label)

for path in iterPaths(modules, "ModuleA"):
    print(path)
```